# Apply "list" function on multiple columns pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, apply

In order to "concatenate" a few rows to 1 list with groupby in Pandas, I can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,2,2,2,2,3],'B':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']})

df = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list)
```

I will get:

```
A
-------------------
1          [a, b]
2    [c, d, e, f]
3             [g]
```

I want to do the same with agg:

```
f = {"B":[list]}
df = df.groupby('A').agg(f)
```

that gives errors,
any idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) - output is `Series`:

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
print (df)
A
1          [a, b]
2    [c, d, e, f]
3             [g]
dtype: object
```

Or with define column `B` in `dict` - output is `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.groupby('A').agg({'B': lambda x: x.tolist()})
print (df)
              B
A              
1        [a, b]
2  [c, d, e, f]
3           [g]
```

Also works:

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(lambda x: list(x))
print (df)
A
1          [a, b]
2    [c, d, e, f]
3             [g]
dtype: object

df = df.groupby('A').agg({'B': lambda x: list(x)})
print (df)
              B
A              
1        [a, b]
2  [c, d, e, f]
3           [g]
```